# The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm provisioning App Service, App Service plan and storage account to existing Resource Group using ARM template. Doing this on a nightly basis. Everything has worked several months but suddenly started to see errors like this:

```
{
 "Code": "BadRequest",
 "Message": "The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one.",
 "Target": null,
 "Details": [
   {
     "Message": "The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one."
   },
   {
     "Code": "BadRequest"
   },
   {
     "ErrorEntity": {
       "ExtendedCode": "59314",
       "MessageTemplate": "The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one.",
       "Parameters": [],
       "Code": "BadRequest",
       "Message": "The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one."
     }
   }
 ],
 "Innererror": null
' Error code: 1201
}
```

There are no changes on ARM template.

I don't have permissions to create new Resource Groups with this subscription, just Resource Group owner to this existing one.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/37287583-allow-a-linux-and-windows-app-service-plan-to-exis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue can be resolved by creating new Linux App Service plan to Resource group and then deleting it. After that Windows App Service plan provisioning works again.

Comment: This worked for me to but have no idea why. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Did you ever find a root cause?

Comment: Never worked for me

Answer (score 2):

> Historically, you can't mix Windows and Linux apps in the same resource group. However, all resource groups created on or after January 21, 2021 do support this scenario. For resource groups created before January 21, 2021, the ability to add mixed platform deployments will be rolled out across Azure regions (including National cloud regions) soon.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations

See also the feature request to support Linux and Windows App Service Plan within the same Resource Group:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/37287583-allow-a-linux-and-windows-app-service-plan-to-exis

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME:**

It seems same OS's (Linux/Windows) App Service Plans (ASP) can not be used in the same Resource Group with same Region.

So what I did was,

- Created a new Resource Group (Optional, if you have it already)
- Deleted all the ASP in the Group (if you are using already created Resource Group)
- Search for "App Service plans" and press Enter
- Click Add
- Specify the Resource Group > Select OS (Linux) > Select Region (East US) > Select SKU > Review + Create.

Again,

- Search for "App Service plans" and press Enter
- Click Add
- Specify the Resource Group > Select OS (Windows) > Select Region (Central US) > Select SKU > Review + Create.

Doing the above steps, resolved my issue. Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I deleted all existing app services and solutions and placeholder in that resource group, then it works